# Disk space disappearing

Tags: windows-server-2008, vps

My Windows 2008 VPS (Parallels) has a problem with disk spacing disappearing. 
I have been using TreeSize free to measure the space in each folder over the last few months.  The first month I lost only 1Gb, then the next month 10th June - 10th July I lost 5.9Gb.   But in the last 7 days I have lost 6.3Gb.

- **2011-06-10**
- Total space: 29.9Gb
- Used: 20Gb
- Free: 6.53Gb
- Unaccounted for: 3.3Gb
- **2011-07-10**
- Total space: 32Gb  (I had to buy 2Gb more)
- Used: 19.9Gb
- Free: 2.9Gb
- Unaccounted for: 9.2Gb
- **2011-07-16**
- Total space: 33.9Gb (I had to buy 2Gb more)
- Used: 17.8Gb
- Free: 0.6Gb
- Unaccounted for: 15.5Gb

I had the same problem on windows 2003 server a few months ago. It ran fine for 2 years. With the following software:

- PHP
- .NET 3.5
- Smarter Mail
- Smarter Stats
- Sync Back
- SQL Server Express
- FileZilla server

After I installed the below software (on my old 2003 server) the problems started. I am not sure if the software is related to the issue or not.

- A newer version of PHP
- MySQL Server
- .NET 4.0
- MVC .NET
- Visual SVN Server
- A OS commerce website

This 2008 server (currently with the problem) has all the software above installed at the sometime. It ran fine for the first one month. Then was a little be bad, now it gets worse and worse each day. At this rate it won't be long before I'm loosing 1Gb per day.

[image]

Comment: It look slike you have the software to manually monitor that (TreeSize). Check for log files. Also it looks like from the screen shot you only have 17.8 GB accounted for on a 33.9 GB partition, with only 650 MB free. I might check your vzquota folder that's showing [Access is denied.], see what's going on in there.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Nixphoe has pointed out, you might also check for stranded temp files and maybe take a look at the swap file settings as well.

On the log file front, if it is appropriate, you might also look into compressing those files/directories. The text-based log files tend to be very compressible.

Comment: Thanks - I have compressed several log folders already? Would using windows compression be causing problems that may attribute to the 15Gb unaccounted for? i.e is it safe to use compression in VPS's?

Comment: Compression would result in the system reporting more storage in use than the actual physical storage committed to you, so it would be a situation where it should favor you.